# Add HTML between feed items

Tags: plugins, jquery, html, rss

I am using a Wordpress plugin called RSS Retriever to display a RSS feed on this page [Manchester United News](http://footballnewsdaily.net/manchester-united/) What i am looking to do is display an advert (HTML) between every other feed title. Is there an easy way to do this without having to edit the plug in.

Sample Code

```
title="Man United ready to smash transfer record to sign star striker">Man United ready to smash transfer record to sign star striker</a><div class="wp_rss_retriever_container"><div class="wp_rss_retriever_metadata"><span class="wp_rss_retriever_date">Published: March 25, 2016 - 12:29 pm</span></div></div></div></li><li class="wp_rss_retriever_item"><div class="wp_rss_retriever_item_wrapper"><a class="wp_rss_retriever_title" target="_blank" href="http://footballnewsdaily.net/manchester-united/fenerbahce-plan-bid-for-manchester-united-ace-mata/"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add some code to the bottom of each feed post, this would give you the desired result. You can add this code to your functions.php or add it as a plugin

```
/** Add custom feed content footer
 * @param $content
 * @return string
 */
function add_feed_content($content) {

    if(is_feed()) {
    $post_type = get_post_type( get_the_ID() );

        $content .= '<footer>'.PHP_EOL;
        $content .= '<p>Some advert here</p>'.PHP_EOL;
        $content .= '</footer>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'add_feed_content');
add_filter('the_content', 'add_feed_content');
```

edit: making the assumption you control the RSS feed, but thinking about your question more, maybe you don't

Comment: I've added the PHP to the web page but it doesn't seem to have made any difference

Comment: Do you control the RSS? If not you could maybe inject something using css and/or jQuery

Comment: Yes I do, Which do you think would be the easier option and what functions etc would i use for CSS

Comment: If you control the source RSS adding my code above, that should work. That's certainly the easiest thing

Comment: I think it might be easier too use CSS as the PHP code which you posted wasn't working correctly. Also all the feed items have a similar HTML (which I've posted now in the original Question), if you could point me in the right direction for a CSS code that would be a great help

Comment: Working on it here - https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=NMsl0rLKoc